# Python: How to read data from a file and do math with it

Tags: python, file, input, output

How do I read in a file input and then say if it's not a year then don't use that data?  If it is a year (4 digit number) then calculate if it's a leap year by doing simple math.

I'm asking more so how do I do this with a file. I can do the math normally but when the file gets involved I have no idea how files work.

edit
Also, how do I do separate functions to check if the input is digits and another function to calculate if it's a leap year or not?

```
file_name_one = input("First file name: ")
file_stream = open(file_name_one, "r")

for line in file_stream:
    year_str = line[:4]
    year = 0
    leap_year = 0
    div_4 = 0
    div_100 = 0
    div_400 = 0

if year_str.isdigit():   # test if year_str is an integer
    year = int(year_str)
    if year%4 == 0:           # check if the year is a leap year
        div_4 = 1
    if year%100 == 0:
        div_100 = 1
    if year%400 == 0:
        div_400 = 1
    if div_4 == 1 & div_100 == 0:
        print (line[:4], "is a leap year" )
    if div_4 == 1 & div_100 == 0 & div_400 == 1:
        print (line[:4], "is a leap year" )
    div_4 = 0
    div_100 = 0
    div_400 = 0
```

Comment: *I have no idea how files work.* Then you'll definitely want to take a peek at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: I have the book, I been reading but I have no idea how it works still.

Comment: The answers below show you how files work. Think of the file object as streaming one line at a time of the file, as a string object, into python. What you do with that string object is up to you. What do you actually want to do with the output and what does the file look like -- this will help us answer your question better. Otherwise, the answers below are sufficient for the question as stated.

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you want to read from file , is it ?

will for that ,it's really easy  :

```
with open("filename","r") as file :
    input = file.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is named "foo.txt" and if you are in the same directory of the file, then something like:

```
file_stream = open("foo.txt",'r')
for line in file_stream:

    # as suggested in the comment, it might be a good idea to print the line, 
    # just so you know what the file looks like
    print line

    # the variable line is a string. depending on the formatting of the file, 
    # something along these lines might work:

    year_str = line[:4]
    if year_str.isdigit():   # test if year_str is an integer
        year = int(year_str)
        if not year%4:           # check if the year is a leap year
           # 
           print "%s is a leap year %s"%year
           ....
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice as well to show the contents of the file that the user reads? So if he wants to run your code he can have a complete example? And maybe some commends about what is going on.

Comment: Depends what your needs are. Perhaps. Perhaps not? It's worth noting (and I will, above) that the question does not specify what one actually wants to do with the data or what the file looks like, how big, etc. This is the general skeleton of how it works -- but finer points depend on intention and the data.

Comment: Agree. I was reading the answer and seemed the best fitted to vote since the question is accepted. I wanted to mention that it could help the OP a bit more.

Comment: Well, the list itself is a bunch of years and some years are not 4 digits and there are alphabet strings that are in there as well that will not be used so the program has to weed those out.

Comment: When there's a line that says "2025 is almost here" it prints the whole thing and calculates that 2025 is a leap year...  How to make it not say the "is almost here" part.

Comment: It should only print the integer part (the first 4 digits).

Comment: NB I just fixed a bug which printed every non-leap year instead of printing leap years :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read multiple lines of data, then readlines() is a good function to know. Try this:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
     print line
```

Modify the fourth line to check whether your data looks like a year.

Comment: Note that this loads the entire file into memory. The nice thing about file objects is that they themselves are iterable -- so you can treat the object as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

For your updated question:

```
import re

def check_is_year(year):
    # implement as per other answers
    return True # if `year` is valid, else return False

def check_is_leap(year):
    # implement as you will
    return True # if `year` is a leap year, else False

with open("foo.txt") as f:
    years = [year for year in re.findall("/b/d{4}/b",f.read()) if check_is_year(year)]
    for year in years:
        if check_is_leap(year):
            # do whatever you want.
```

Comment: @user3294540 `re` is the module that handles regular expressions in Python. later on I use `re.findall("/b/d{4}/b",f.read())`, which matches the regular expression `/b/d{4}/b` (`/b` is a word boundary, e.g. a space or tab or etc, `/d` is a digit 1234567890, and `{4}` means it has to match 4 of the previous statement)